# Using Sherlock in Google Colab or Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, social-networking

I have a list of Twitter users and I want to check if they have accounts on other social media platforms. For that, I've come across an application called Sherlock that runs directly on the computer's command prompt (cmd).

My question is whether it's possible to use that application in Google Colab or a similar IDE, as I don't feel comfortable working directly in the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google Colab or a similar IDE for running `sherlock` but you have to follow installation instructions mentioned [here](https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock/tree/master). Then you can run `sherlock` using [this](https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock/blob/master/sherlock/sherlock.py) python code in your IDE.